# Create a combination of a array of hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array like:

```
hasharray=[{"a" => "b" } , {"c" => "d"} , {"e" => "f"}]
```

I want to create all combinations of this array hash of length `min` to `max`.

For instance, with `min=0` and `max=2`, the code should return:

```
resultarray=[
{},
 {"a" => "b" },
{"c" => "d"},
{"e" => "f"},
{"a" => "b" } , {"c" => "d"},
{"c" => "d"} , {"e" => "f"},
{"a" => "b" },{"e" => "f"}
]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe there's an easier way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you might be confused about how hashes work. The value of a hash is storing *many* key-value pairs. Knowing more about what you're trying to do would be a big help, but offhand I think your data structure needs some tweaking first.

Answer (score 3):

```
min = 0
max = 2
min.upto(max).flat_map {|n| hasharray.combination(n).to_a }
# => [
#   [],
#   [{"a"=>"b"}], [{"c"=>"d"}], [{"e"=>"f"}],
#   [{"a"=>"b"}, {"c"=>"d"}], [{"a"=>"b"}, {"e"=>"f"}], [{"c"=>"d"}, {"e"=>"f"}]
# ]
```

Comment: I fail to see how your answer generates the result as OP has mentioned?

Comment: I think he forgot enclosing arrays in his notation, otherwise the question does not make a lot of sense. Have you even thought about what one could do with the code? Just returning an array like the op posted is useless, however he did the correct grouping by putting the hashes on separate lines.

Comment: @Surya in my opinion the worst answers on SO are posted by those who fail to look behind the question and find out what the OP really needs. All too often, answers only revolve around producing _exactly_ the result the OP requested, although that is often not the best solution. If you don't understand what the question is, don't downvote.

Comment: @p11y true, but you could ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: @p11y I got your poin, thanks for clarification. But I'm not the one who down voted the answer.

Comment: @Stefan Actually that makes a lot sense as some times op's not clear with their questions.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer. I wanted it in the form resultarray=[
{},
 {"a" => "b" },
{"c" => "d"},
{"e" => "f"},
{{"a" => "b" } , {"c" => "d"}},
{{"c" => "d"} , {"e" => "f"}},
{{"a" => "b" },{"e" => "f"}}
]

Comment: any idea how to get the result in this form . I tried this on the result of answer given by @p11y - resultarray.map! { |a| a[0]} but that did not work.

Comment: thanks guys I got the result in the form I wanted thanks for your help

Comment: @user27111987 a hash is a list of pairs of values, but combinations can only be a list, therefore you will find arrays `[ ... ]` on the second level of nesting, not hashes `{ ... }`.

Comment: @user27111987 the single elements are also enclosed in arrays to be consistent - they're a one-element list. For n=0 you get a 0-element list: the empty array `[]`. For n=1 you get one element lists, for example `{"a"=>"b"}`. For n=2 you get two element-lists, and so on. If the single hashes were not enclosed as well, we would treat them specially and it would be more difficult to iterate over the structure. There's no reason for that.

Comment: @Surya sorry didnt mean to offend you.

Comment: @p11y you can't spend hours digging into an asker's problem set on StackOverflow. I think you did the best you could - answering the question that was asked. I also learned a new trick - I've been programming Ruby for years, and didn't know about the `combination` method!

Comment: @p11y : Yes bro.. you are right.. Bydway thanks for to be aware of new method `combination` 1+